# How to not lost all data in production mode after database migration in development mode in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, capistrano

I am working on a rails app with a few git branches. we deploy the production mode using Capistrano::Rails.

What currently struggling me is that I added and deleted a few columns in the user table in a branch, and after merge it into the master branch, I ran `rake db:schema:load`. So the database in development mode is reset and all data is lost(which is fine). However, I don't want to lose all of my data in the production mode. In the production database, I could accept losing the data in the user table, but I don't want to lose the data in other tables on my production mode.

So what shall I do for that.

We currently use PostgreSQL on AWS RDS.

Comment: you should simply run `rake db:migrate` to migrate your new columns that won't delete past data apart from of course the ones in the column you deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ActiveRecord migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) were created for this purpose. Rather than run `rake db:schema:load`, make your database changes through migrations and run `rake db:migrate` (or `rails db:migrate` if Rails 5)